# Sparql query to get most common paths?

Tags: sparql, rdf

If I have a database that consists of thousands of directed graphs with each graph consisting of less than 50 nodes with the same URLs used throughout the entire database,  how would I find the most common paths throughout all the directed graphs ?

Here is a small example:

```
(4)<-(1)->(2)->(3)    
(19)<-(1)->(2)->(3)->(25)
(12)<-(1)->(41) , (1)->(2)->(3)->(14)
```

Notice here, the path from 1,2,3 is common

How would I find the most common path (or the top 3) in the entire RDF database like this with SPARQL ?

Comment: This is rather broad. Please show what your data looks like in actual RDF (for example: are you using named graphs to distinguish different graphs, or some other modelling approach)? And what have you tried sofar in terms of a query?

Comment: Also: while it might be possible to do what you want, SPARQL as a language is not really suited for this kind of graph-analysis. It's possible that using the extended API of whatever RDF database you're storing this in will give you a better solution.